# Help with NVidia GeForce 9400 GT?

Tags: nvidia, 13.04, graphics

I just got my 13.04 running.

However, I run off an almost ancient graphics card, the NVidia GeForce 9400 GT, and it doesn't support the dimensions for my card, is there any drivers I could possibly get? I've attempted looking in the driver update panel in the system settings, but no avail.

Comment: have you tried nVidia website?  What do you mean by saying " it doesn't support the dimensions for my card"?

Comment: I solved it by switching to proprietary drivers instead of x.org open source.